How can I open an SharePoint Library item in a PowerApps Canvas app with metadata?
I've got a request in a SharePoint Library that requires these steps:

User selects Create New Document Set in the Library by filling out a SharePoint default form with various fields (choice, y/n, people pickers, date, text).
An email gets sent to an Approver.
The Approver opens the submitted form, selects Approve or Reject from a Choice field (Radio buttons).
Requestor receives an email

The problem I'm having is that this requirement also asks for more field/display customization that a SharePoint default form (json) can do.  So I went ahead and built a Canvas app, connected to this library, added the same fields.  How could I populate the Canvas app with the data of submitted Library items?  I want the Approver(s) to provide their responses in the Canvas app, not the SharePoint form.
I would need to tell the app to identify (probably based on item ID) what to populate those fields with.
Any help would be great.
Thank you.
